# NodeJS - Modularising SQLite3

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, sqlite

I like to split out my code where possible - and having SQL in a route makes me cringe.

Node JS is new to me and I'm learning it at the moment, but I'm having a problem with the following (the page just hangs and doesn't serve anything).

It makes sense to me with my current level of knowledge - but I imagine there will be a better way of doing this.

Thank you for taking the time for reading this, and your help is greatly appreciated.

---

**Route**

```
var express   = require('express');
var router    = express.Router();
var db        = require('../lib/db.js');

var model     = require('../models/contacts.js');

/* GET contacts. */
router.get('/', function(req, res) {

  // Get data from model - RETURN THE ROWSET HERE
  model.get_names(db, function(rowset) {

    res.render('contacts', { 
      title: 'Contacts | Rhubarb',
      nav_active: "contacts",
    }, function(err, output) {
      res.status(200).send(rowset);  
    }); // res.render

  }); // model.get_names

}); // router

module.exports = router;
```

**Model**

```
module.exports.get_names = function(db) {

  var sql = " SELECT attr_name " +
            "      , attr_value " +  
            "   FROM contacts  a " +
            "      , contact_attributes b " +
            "  WHERE a.contact_id = b.contact_id " +
            "    AND (attr_name = 'forename' OR attr_name = 'surname')";


   db.all(sql, function(err, rowset) {

     if (err) throw err;
     return rowset;

   }); // db.all

}  // get_names
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted it by adding an actual call back to the function... *sigh*...

```
module.exports.get_names = function(db, callback) {

  var sql = " SELECT attr_name " +
            "      , attr_value " +  
            "   FROM contacts  a " +
            "      , contact_attributes b " +
            "  WHERE a.contact_id = b.contact_id " +
            "    AND (attr_name = 'forename' OR attr_name = 'surname')";


  return db.all(sql, function(err, rowset) {
    if (err) throw err;

    return callback(rowset);

  });

}
```